# Oh no, I just bought this shirt!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Spherical things into pockets are falling,
>   riches in colourful arcs' ends calling,
>   teatime and honey and flowers recalling,
>   money to win in the middle, we're all in!
>
> Park my car into the gym's space ingressing,
>   someone's supporting me while I'm bench pressing,
>   ladies with my leopard-print clothes impressing,
>   notice a stain on my shirt while undressing!?
>
> Selling the poles from my fence I've been musing,
>   wrote on this forum online I'm now using,
>   offered to mail to a place of their choosing,
>   moving the goals when my argument's losing.
>
> Freeze! Halt! Prevent that young man from departing,
>   right past a red traffic sign he is darting,
>   people are waiting for bus ride's restarting,
>   consonants start bed, car, tree, dark and parting.

How are we related?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My observation:

> All the lines in the 1st verse are describing types of **POTS** (Billiard ball pot, the pot of gold at the end of a rainbow, pot of honey, jackpot).
>  All the lines in the 2nd verse are describing different interpretations for **SPOT** (A parking spot, 'spotting' someone at the gym, leopard spots, spot on a stained shirt).
>  All the lines in the 3rd verse are describing different usages of the word **POST** (Fence post, forum post, mail post, goal post).
>  All the lines in the 4th verse are describing usages of the word **STOP** (Stop!, stoplight, bus stop and 'stop consonants' (such as b, c, t, d & p).
>
>  **So these are all anagrams of one another.** (Which, this answerer opts to say, is the tops!)

Comment: (Well done! But I think you may be overthinking the last line, [see here, noun 1.6](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stop))

Comment: @MOehm D'oh! Why didn't I think of that? :/ Thanks! [Edited]